# Exim4: all relevant MX records point to non-existent hosts

Tags: email, debian, email-server, exim

I'm currently having an issue with exim4. Some mail isn't delivered. I found this in my rejected log.

```
2012-06-21 10:11:47 H=bart (bart.*.com) [192.168.171.145] F=<info@****.com> rejected RCPT <xxxx@dresssmall.com>: all relevant MX records point to non-existent hosts
```

Is this an issue with my server or rather with the recepients server?

Comment: See https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2006/03/msg03177.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DNS server of the recipient domain isn't configured properly. You can find more information about the problem on [the Exim wiki](https://github.com/Exim/exim/wiki/Q0302).

**Edit:** Now when I have the recipient domain, here's some updated information. The MX servers for the domain are:

```
$ dig +short mx dresssmall.com
8 smtp.dresssmall.com.
9 pop.dresssmall.com.
10 mail.dresssmall.com.
7 pop3.dresssmall.com.
```

The problem is that they don't have proper A records:

```
$ dig pop3.dresssmall.com | grep NXDOMAIN
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 60414
```

Above I pasted only the MX with lowest priority for brevity, but all of them doesn't have A records.

Comment: When I fetch the dns records for the host I get valid hostnames.; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> dresssmall.com mx
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52851
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dresssmall.com.   IN MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
dresssmall.com.  600 IN MX 8 smtp.dresssmall.com.
dresssmall.com.  600 IN MX 10 mail.dresssmall.com.
dresssmall.com.  600 IN MX 7 pop3.dresssmall.com.
dresssmall.com.  600 IN MX 9 pop.dresssmall.com.

Comment: You get valid hostnames for the MX records, but neither of them resolves properly - they don't have A records in the DNS.

Comment: I edited my answer above with some more information added.